# JSX element type 'Navbar' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

export const NavbarPage = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
    </>
    )
}
```

I've looked through multiple posts saying to export the function and I swear that's what I am doing with 
`export const NavbarPage = () => {`
 but TS isn't liking that either. Any idea?

Comment: try doing export default const. if you dont have it as a default export, when you import it you will have to use a different synatx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

export default class BottomNav extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
      <>
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="bottom">
          <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">Blake Alonzo</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="portfolio">Porfolio</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="music">Music</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the updated version of getting everything to work. One method to get this working is to extend *Component* class from react library. This allows up to modify the class and add Navbar, Container, and Nav into the newly created class for use in other components (pages).
Make sure you export all of your files to the components folder to use them easily in other components and the index.tsx file.

Lastly the src/index.tsx (because I'm using typescript) needs an import line that takes the CSS directly from the bootstrap.min.css file.

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This will be one of your imports. After that this should show in your page.